# Emacs: how to have query-replace cycle through the buffer?

Tags: emacs, replace, buffer

if I am starting at some position in the buffer, i can only perform query-replace for the rest of buffer in one run. Is there any way to let query-replace cycle through the buffer?

Answer (score 2):

Use `M-<` to go to the beginning of the buffer, before you use `M-%` to query-replace.

If you want a command that does that, write it:

```
(defun my-qr ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (call-interactively #'query-replace))
```

And if you want to return to where you started when done, then wrap the code in `save-excursion`.

```
(defun my-qr ()
  "..."
  (save-excursion
   (interactive)
   (goto-char (point-min))
   (call-interactively #'query-replace)))
```

Comment: But what if the user doesn't always want to start from the beginning? E.g. he prefers the current behavior of replacing in the rest of the buffer, but sometimes, when replace gets to the end, he wants to continue from the beginning. So the best solution would be some kind of question when replace gets to the end to ask the user if he wants to continue from the beginning of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I've using below for work with Emacs 24+:

```
;; query replace all from buffer start
(fset 'my-query-replace-all 'query-replace)
(advice-add 'my-query-replace-all
            :around
            #'(lambda(oldfun &rest args)
               "Query replace the whole buffer."
               ;; set start pos
               (unless (nth 3 args)
                 (setf (nth 3 args)
                       (if (region-active-p)
                           (region-beginning)
                         (point-min))))
               (unless (nth 4 args)
                 (setf (nth 4 args)
                       (if (region-active-p)
                           (region-end)
                         (point-max))))
               (apply oldfun args)))
(global-set-key "\C-cr" 'my-query-replace-all)
```

Regard the region replace case, and any START and END args passed.